# Self contained GTK application when there is no X windows environment

Tags: linux, gtk, x11

I am using a very stripped down version of Linux, I want to create a self contained GTK application on a system that has no X window environment installed. 
I want to use GTK GUI classes and widgets and not create a server version where GUI is disabled.

The only thing you can expect is a working glibc.

*From what I understand it would involve the following:*

Statically link GTK lib with X libraries.

Statically link my application with the above mentioned library.


Is there anything to watch out for, Can a (somewhat) newbie get it done. I used google, but (some usable) information flew over my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GTK and X are independent programs. You would typically need to install both for the program to work. Alternatively, you can use the Linux framebuffer by switching out GTK for GTKfb. You will need to compile GTKfb and its dependencies statically if you don't want to distribute the libraries. Carefully read the LGPL if you do this. Red Hat has a paper on building small applications with GTKfb: http://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/gtkfb.pdf.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was searching for.

Answer (score 3):

X libraries are X11 client libraries that are used to connect to X11 server. Your device does not run such server, and X11 client libraries won't be of any help. On embedded devices, the good option is probably to use direct access to framebuffer (e.g., gtk-directfb, gtk-fb)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this; however most of the X / Gtk libraries are normally compiled dynamically, and while they should compile statically you may encounter some bit-rot.

Have you considered simply bundling all the required shared libraries with your application? You could launch your application via a shell script wrapper which sets up the library search path to point to the directory with your shared libraries in.

This is similar to the method that firefox uses on Linux for it's plugin path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use X Virtual Framebuffer.  On Debian, it's the xvfb package.  The following is from the package description:

> Xvfb provides an X server that can
>   run on machines with no display
>   hardware  and no physical input
>   devices. It emulates a dumb
>   framebuffer using virtual  memory. The
>   primary use of this server was
>   intended to be server testing,  but
>   other novel uses for it have been
>   found, including testing clients 
>   against unusual depths and screen
>   configurations, doing batch processing
>   with  Xvfb as a background rendering
>   engine, load testing, as an aid to
>   porting the  X server to a new
>   platform, and providing an unobtrusive
>   way to run  applications that don't
>   really need an X server but insist on
>   having one  anyway.
>
> This package also contains a
>   convenience script called xvfb-run
>   which  simplifies the automated
>   execution of X clients in a virtual
>   server  environment. This convenience
>   script requires the use of the xauth 
>   program.
>
> More information about X.Org can be
>   found at:
>
> http://www.X.org
>
> http://xorg.freedesktop.org
>
> http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/xorg
>
> This package is built from the X.org
>   xserver module.